# How to use Navicat to connect to the MySQL database in Openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift, navicat

I'm using openshift to build my apps.
And I add mysql to my gear.
but, if I want to reach my database. I can't use Navicat which is my usual way to manage my database. I must ssh to my openshift server and then use command line 'mysql' to reach my database which is a bad way compared to Navicat.

So, how can I reach my database in Openshift with Navicat?

I've used `env | grep MYSQL` to get my mysql configration and use it in Navicat.
However, all is none effect.

Answer (score 0):

If its a scalable application you should be able to connect to it externally via the connection information supplied by the environment variables. If its not a scalable app, then you'll need to use the `rhc port-forward` command to forward the necessary ports needed to connect.

Take a look at the following article here for more information. https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift